# Android. Скрипт контроля версий и "слияния" баз данных

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite, sql-merge

Всем доброго времени суток!

В последнее время возникла проблема контроля версий базы данных в приложении, поэтому решил написать скрипт для решения проблемы. Участвую в большом проекте, и заказчик бывает очень переменчив, и частенько приходиться перестраивать структуру базы, но так, чтобы пользователи с предыдущей версией не потеряли своих персональных данных. Для этого и написал свой [SQLiteMergerHelper](https://github.com/Nuclominus/Android-SQLiteMergerHelper), позволяющий на лету реконструировать базу данных и в то же время легко отследить, какие изменения вносились в той или иной версии.

Проблема в том, что сыровато, и хотелось бы услышать советы по дополнениям в функционале, изменениям и оптимизации текущего и в целом любые предложения. Критика приветствуется. Заранее всем спасибо! Постараюсь довести до ума для пользования массами.

Comment: Технология миграций?

Comment: По сути - да, но без лишнего функционала работы с базой данных. Т.е. мне не нужна целая библиотека, а только решение одной атомарной проблемы. Работа с базой была еще до того как я попал в проект. А меня подписали сделать миграцию) и хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы этим можно было пользоваться и в других проектах, без головной боли.